# How to insert a processing instruction in XML file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree, processing-instruction

I want to add a `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction before the root element in my XML file using ElementTree (Python 3.8).

You find as below my code that I used to create XML file

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

def Export_star_xml( self ):
        star_element = ET.Element("STAR",**{ 'xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' })
        element_node = ET.SubElement(star_element ,"STAR_1")
        element_node.text = "Mario adam"
        tree.write( "star.xml" ,encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True )
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<STAR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <STAR_1> Mario adam </STAR_1>
</STAR>
```

Output Expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ResourceFiles/form_star.xsl"?>
<STAR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <STAR_1> Mario adam </STAR_1>
</STAR>
```

Comment: There is a method for this, but I'm not sure how to use it in order to add the PI before the root element. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ProcessingInstruction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot figure out how to do this with ElementTree. Here is a solution that uses [lxml](https://lxml.de/index.html), which provides an `addprevious()` method on elements.

```
from lxml import etree as ET

# Note the use of nsmap. The syntax used in the question is not accepted by lxml
star_element = ET.Element("STAR", nsmap={'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'})
element_node = ET.SubElement(star_element ,"STAR_1")
element_node.text = "Mario adam"

# Create PI and and insert it before the root element
pi = ET.ProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", text='type="text/xsl" href="ResourceFiles/form_star.xsl"')
star_element.addprevious(pi)

ET.ElementTree(star_element).write("star.xml", encoding="utf-8",
                                   xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True)
```

Result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ResourceFiles/form_star.xsl"?>
<STAR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <STAR_1>Mario adam</STAR_1>
</STAR>
```