# Im trying to add additional information next to the prolog on a xml file using python and ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, processing-instruction

Should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?constant='value',constant2='value2'?><?constant3='value3',constant4='value4'?>
```

Ive tried with element tree but I've found nothing

Comment: So you want to add two processing instructions immediately after the XML declaration?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/61252951/407651

Comment: just one actually but i dont know how to add a <?...?> into the xml, currently ive inserted it manually. the idea is to insert <?app="name"?> using ET